# Can't put an image inside appbar Flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to put an image to my appbar so it will be showing in the appbar. But I couldn't made it and I have no idea why. I called the image in title as child of container.

My appbar codes:

```
appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: _height * .15,
        title: Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height * .03),
            height: _height * .1,
            width: _width * .7,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: _height * .08,
                  width: _width * .23,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
                    width: _width * .2,
                    height: _height * .08,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

in pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
  - assets/images/logo.png
```

and assets are just a folder in my projects and inside it images folder and inside logo.png. Why I can't show the image? Trying on flutter web / chrome.

An image for that is:
[image]

I want the image in red part.

Edit: I changed my scaffold. I deleted appbar and tried to put them in Column as body. But that did not work too:

```
return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height * .02, left: _width * .04),
              height: _height * .12,
              width: _width * .9,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
                    width: _width * .2,
                    height: _height * .08,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: _height * .12,
                    width: _width * .6,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height * .08),
                            width: _width * .11,
                            height: _height * .03,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            child: Center(
                                child: TextButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Ana Sayfa",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: _height * .016),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                return null;
                              },
                            ))),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height * .08),
                            width: _width * .11,
                            height: _height * .03,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            child: Center(
                                child: TextButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Hakkımızda",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: _height * .016),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                return null;
                              },
                            ))),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height * .08),
                            width: _width * .11,
                            height: _height * .03,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            child: Center(
                                child: TextButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Giriş Yap",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: _height * .016),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                return null;
                              },
                            ))),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height * .08),
                            width: _width * .11,
                            height: _height * .03,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            child: Center(
                                child: TextButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Üyelik Oluştur",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: _height * .016),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                return null;
                              },
                            ))),
                        Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _height * .08),
                            width: _width * .11,
                            height: _height * .03,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            child: Center(
                                child: TextButton(
                              child: Text(
                                "Mağaza",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: _height * .016),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                return null;
                              },
                            )))
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ));
```

Comment: What is the value of _height  and _width? What's with all these ratios too? I am honestly not surprised this has bugs. Its full of bad code.

Comment: They are MediaQuery.of().size's height and width. I just started, thanks.

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: try "flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html"

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the Image widget instead of Center (at title:).
And then set

```
centerTitle: true;
```

Make sure that you restart the app when changes are made in the pubspec file.

Comment: Do you mean title's child will be Image? If that's the case, I will put some buttons and containers inside appbar, too. So It will not be all image. Will that work for that?

Comment: I added an image what I meant.

Comment: I don't think that will be the right use of the app bar.

Comment: you can just add row below the app bar or just completely remove the appbar and create a row at the beginning of the scaffold.

Comment: Yes, I see that would be a solution but isn't there any way to do that with appbar?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what your error is, but whatever you're trying to do is wrong practice. Better way to do it is by either scaling the image or resizing it to fit the appbar.

Possiable example:

```
AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/logo.png',
                width: 55,
                height: 55,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              child: Text('Title'),
              color: Colors.green,
            ))
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Comment: I don't get any errors. I just can't see the image. Inside container or anywhere.

Comment: Make sure the image isn't too small, make sure you save logo.png inside assets/images/, and then restart your app.

Comment: Hardcoding constraints isn't a good practice as well. Ideally you'd make the image fit the height while keeping the original aspect ratio.

Comment: @mightybruno That is incorrect. Hard-coding constraints is perfectly fine so long as the constraint hasn't possibility to be out of bound. In this case, so long as you know the size of your image, its perfectly fine.